# browserify-istanbul always returns 100%

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, code-coverage, browserify

I have a dead simple project (for the shake of asking this question). I used browserify to bundle my project, karma/jasmine as the testing framework, and browserify-instanbul for code coverage:

The problem is when I run `npm test`, all the tests pass, terminal is green. But then when I check the coverage, there is nothing valuable there:

[image]
I can see that the unit tests testing mechanism work normally. I tried to make 1 test fail and it did reveal the failed test, however, the test coverage was still the same as the picture above.

Here are what I have:

Files under src folder:

```
animal.js
animal.spec.js
dog.js
dog.spec.js
```

Where the content of each source file can be simple as following:

animal.js:

```
function openMouth(){
    return 'openMouth';
}

module.exports = {
    openMouth: openMouth
};
```

dog.js:

```
var animal = require("./animal.js");

function say() {
    animal.openMouth();
    return 'woof';
}

module.exports = {
    say: say
};
```

The specs files just verify the output of each function. So something like this:

dog.spec.js:

```
var dog = require("./dog.js");
describe('dog', function () {
    it('should be able to say woof', function () {
        expect(dog.say()).toBe('woof');
    });
});
```

my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    autoWatch: true,
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js'
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors: {
        'src/**/*.spec.js': ['browserify'],
        'src/**/!(*.spec).js': ['browserify']
    },
    singleRun: true,

    plugins: [
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],
    transform: [
      ['browserify-istanbul',
        {
          instrumenterConfig: {
            embedSource: true   // this is important for HTML reports
          }
        }
      ]
    ]

  });
};
```

Comment: Summary says Lines (0/0). Seems code coverage tool is not set up correclty.

Comment: I know, that's why I asked how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating my karma config as following:

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    autoWatch: true,
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      'src/*.js'
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors: {
        'src/*.js': ['browserify']
    },
    browserify: {
      //debug: true,
      transform: ['browserify-istanbul']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
        reporters : [
            {"type": "text"},
            {"type": "html", dir: 'coverages'}
        ]
    },
    singleRun: true,
    plugins: [
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ]
  });
};
```

Remember to install `instanbul` also.